# Error when trying to install IPBoard (Invision Power Board)

Tags: php, mysql, installation

I'm currently trying to install invision power board as the forum provider for my website, but no matter what I do when i go to /community/ or /admin/install/ i get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnWh7.png

I'm with 000webhost and i'm fairly sure they're not the cause, i've also created a MYSQL database for later on in the installation.

I also ensured that all of the files uploaded to the host and double checked this afterwards.

EDIT: The code located within index.php is:

```
<?php
/**
 * @brief       Installer bootstrap
 * @author      <a href='http://www.invisionpower.com'>Invision Power Services, Inc.</a>
 * @copyright   (c) 2001 - SVN_YYYY Invision Power Services, Inc.
 * @license     http://www.invisionpower.com/legal/standards/
 * @package     IPS Social Suite
 * @since       2 Apr 2013
 * @version     SVN_VERSION_NUMBER
 */

require_once '../../init.php';
\IPS\Dispatcher\Setup::i()->setLocation('install')->run();
```

Comment: Please describe what you have done so far to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: `Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\'` indicates an outdated PHP version, which doesn't support PHP 5.3 namespaces. (Now this is a guessed comment, because you didn't show the relevant code, as you should have. And don't post screenshots.)

Comment: @leonidglanz I've tried deleting the community folder from filezilla on the webhost and then reuploading the file, to which i had no avail.

Comment: @mario The code located in index.php is:
<?php

require_once '../../init.php';
\IPS\Dispatcher\Setup::i()->setLocation('install')->run();

Also, updated post sorry for misinforming you with the screenshot.

Comment: PHP version. Find a better hoster.

Comment: @mario So will no version of the software be able to be installed with this host? Or could i use an older version for instance IPBoard 3.0 (the one i currently have is IPBoard 4.0)